# Infinispan - ISPN000476: Timed out waiting for responses for request

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, infinispan

I'm creating a `CacheService` `Singleton` on a `JBoss 7.2` server using `infinispan 7.2.5` and I'm getting timeout errors during communication. I tried increasing the timeout from the default to 35000 milliseconds but that didn't help. Is there anything that stands out about my config that may cause these errors?

**Error**

```
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: ISPN000476: Timed out waiting for responses for request 387 from devserver-44351
.....
Caused by: org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: ISPN000476: Timed out waiting for responses for request 387 from devserver-44351
```

**Startup Code**

```
  @PostConstruct
        void start() {
            logger.info("Starting cache service...");
            GlobalConfiguration gc = new GlobalConfigurationBuilder().transport().defaultTransport()
                    .globalJmxStatistics().allowDuplicateDomains(true).cacheManagerName("Cache").build();
            Configuration config = new ConfigurationBuilder().clustering().cacheMode(CacheMode.REPL_SYNC).sync().replTimeout(35000).build();
    
            cacheManager = new DefaultCacheManager(gc);
            cacheManager.defineConfiguration("times", config);
    
            lastGetTimesCache = cacheManager.getCache("times");
            logger.info("Cache service started!");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a jgroups configuration solved this problem

```
@PostConstruct
        void start() {
            logger.info("Starting cache service...");
            GlobalConfiguration gc = new GlobalConfigurationBuilder().transport().defaultTransport()
           .addProperty("configurationFile", "infinispan-jgroups.xml").globalJmxStatistics().allowDuplicateDomains(true).cacheManagerName("Cache").build();
            Configuration config = new ConfigurationBuilder().clustering().cacheMode(CacheMode.REPL_SYNC).sync().replTimeout(35000).build();
    
            cacheManager = new DefaultCacheManager(gc);
            cacheManager.defineConfiguration("times", config);
    
            lastGetTimesCache = cacheManager.getCache("times");
            logger.info("Cache service started!");
        }
```